# Extending a software RAID1 configuration

Tags: raid, luks, software-raid

There is a system with 2 equivalent HDDs (both are 4TB), and they are "bind" together with *raid1*:

```
$ sudo mdadm --query --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Oct  8 22:22:53 2017
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 3906887488 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 3906887488 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Fri Aug  4 19:48:49 2023
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : -------:0  (local to host -------)
              UUID : -------
            Events : 13519

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       1       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
```

On top of them there are also volume-groups, based on @roaima's answer I could now identify the configuration:

```
sda                           8:0    0   3.7T  0 disk
└─md0                         9:0    0   3.7T  0 raid1
  └─md0p1                   259:1    0   3.7T  0 part
    └─lukslvm-XXXXXXXXX     253:3    0   3.7T  0 crypt
      ├─vg--XXXXXXXXX-AAAA  253:4    0   500G  0 lvm   /media/AAAA
      └─vg--XXXXXXXXX-BBBB  253:5    0   3.2T  0 lvm   /media/BBBB
sdb                           8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk
└─md0                         9:0    0   3.7T  0 raid1
  └─md0p1                   259:1    0   3.7T  0 part
    └─lukslvm-XXXXXXXXX     253:3    0   3.7T  0 crypt
      ├─vg--XXXXXXXXX-AAAA  253:4    0   500G  0 lvm   /media/AAAA
      └─vg--XXXXXXXXX-BBBB  253:5    0   3.2T  0 lvm   /media/BBBB
```

Assuming this configuration, how can I replace these disks to larger (let's say 8TB), **without losing anything** (note: there no more physical connectors on the mainboard) ?

Replacing one 4TB to a 8TB, then wait until raid1 state for both HDDs become `active sync`, then replace the other 4TB to 8TB, and again wait for `active sync`? And then obviously extend the VG and extend the FS?

Comment: You might find it less nerve-wracking to mount a new empty 8 GiB raid volume, and use `rsync -a -v  /data4gig  /data8gig`. Then repeat the command, and notice that it completes almost immediately, whereupon you can umount to rename the volume.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to start from the top with the filesystem and work logically downwards. (That actually means working upwards through the output from `lsblk`, though.)

```
lsblk

NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0                 179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1             179:1    0   63M  0 part  /boot
├─mmcblk0p2             179:2    0    8G  0 part  /
└─mmcblk0p3             179:3    0 21.7G  0 part
  ├─pi_p3-raid1a        254:2    0    1G  0 lvm
  │ └─md1                 9:1    0 1022M  0 raid1
  │   └─crypt_md1       254:4    0 1006M  0 crypt
  │     └─vgtest-lvtest 254:5    0  100M  0 lvm   /mnt/dsk
  └─pi_p3-raid1b        254:3    0    1G  0 lvm
    └─md1                 9:1    0 1022M  0 raid1
      └─crypt_md1       254:4    0 1006M  0 crypt
        └─vgtest-lvtest 254:5    0  100M  0 lvm   /mnt/dsk
```

In your case you would want to start with the root filesystem. In my case this is an SD card partition `mmcblkp02`, which isn't very helpful for the illustration, so instead I created a layer starting with an ext4 file system mounted on `/mnt/dsk`. Let's follow that.

1. `/mnt/dsk` is an `ext4` filesystem labelled `ext4test`

   ```
   findmnt /mnt/dsk

   TARGET   SOURCE                    FSTYPE OPTIONS
   /mnt/dsk /dev/mapper/vgtest-lvtest ext4   rw,relatime,data=ordered
   ```
2. Moving up the tree we can see it is an LVM component created from the device `crypt_md1`. We can confirm the LV and VG names with `lvs` and `pvs`, and indeed they are `lvtest` for the filesystem LV and `vgtest` for the VG:

   ```
   lvs

     LV      VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
     lvtest  vgtest -wi-ao---- 100.00m

   pvs

     PV                    VG     Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
     /dev/mapper/crypt_md1 vgtest lvm2 a--  1004.00m 904.00m
   ```
3. Moving up the tree one more level we can see that `crypt_md1` is a `crypto_LUKS` device built on top of `md1`
4. Up one more level and we can identify that `md1` is a `linux_raid_member`. A quick side-step to `cat /proc/mdstat` will confirm this:

   ```
   cat /proc/mdstat

   Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid1]
   md1 : active raid1 dm-3[1] dm-2[0]
         1046528 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

   unused devices: <none>
   ```
5. Now confusingly perhaps, we can now see my smoke and mirrors: I created the two RAID mirror halves for `md1` from another existing LVM VG, `pi_p3`. This is true: I created two components `raid1a` and `raid1b` and then used `mdadm --create` to build the RAID1 mirror for this example, meaning that I have "Physical → VG → 2x LV → 2x RAID → MD(RAID1) → LUKS → VG → LV → EXT4"! Here are the full set of commands I used for the build, bearing in mind I already had the LVM VG `/dev/pi_p3`:

   ```
   lvcreate --size 1G --name raid1a /dev/pi_p3
   lvcreate --size 1G --name raid1b /dev/pi_p3
   mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level 1 --raid-devices 2 /dev/pi_p3/raid1{a,b}

   cryptsetup -c aes-xts-plain -s 512 -y luksFormat /dev/md1    # "test"
   cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md1 crypt_md1

   pvcreate /dev/mapper/crypt_md1
   vgcreate vgtest /dev/mapper/crypt_md1
   lvcreate --size 100M --name lvtest vgtest

   mkfs -L ext4test -t ext4 /dev/vgtest/lvtest
   mount /dev/vgtest/lvtest /mnt/dsk
   ```

In your case you should be seeing two physical devices rather than my LVM components `raid1a` and `raid1b` so I'm going to stop the analysis here.

If your structure is not what you expect, i.e. it is not "*RAID -> LUKS -> LVM -> FS configuration*" then you should by now have been able to identify the true structure using this approach.

---

Now as to the second part of your question, how to grow the structure with larger disks. I am going to implement this as a worked example by replacing my 1GB `raid1a` and `raid1b` LVs with 2GB `raid1c` and `raid1d`:

```
# Synthesise two "larger disks" from the VG
lvcreate --size 2G --name raid1c /dev/pi_p3
lvcreate --size 2G --name raid1d /dev/pi_p3

# Swap out the first disk
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --add /dev/pi_p3/raid1c
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --set-faulty /dev/pi_p3/raid1a
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --remove /dev/pi_p3/raid1a

# Wait for synchronisation to complete!
cat /proc/mdstat
```

**Wait until the synchronisation has completed**. If you do not wait you *will* lose the entire filesystem and its data at the next step.

```
# Swap out the second disk
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --add /dev/pi_p3/raid1d
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --set-faulty /dev/pi_p3/raid1b
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --remove /dev/pi_p3/raid1b

# Grow the new RAID1 array
mdadm --grow /dev/md1 --size max

# Resize the encrypted layer
cryptsetup resize /dev/mapper/crypt_md1

# Resize the PV for the LVM VG
pvresize /dev/mapper/crypt_md1
```

At this point you should see confirmation that the PV has been successfully resized:

```
  Physical volume "/dev/mapper/crypt_md1" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
```

Now `pvs /dev/mapper/crypt_md1` and `vgs vgtest` will show the new size as 2GB (the size of the new "disks"):

```
  PV                    VG     Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/mapper/crypt_md1 vgtest lvm2 a--  1.98g 1.88g

  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  vgtest   1   1   0 wz--n- 1.98g 1.88g
```

Finally, remember to wait until the second RAID1 synchronisation has completed before powering off or otherwise rebooting your system:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I needed. Now I could identify perfectly my layout. Can you also answer the other half of my question on: how can I replace the disks to larger ones?

Comment: @Daniel I'm away on holiday for a few days. If you build a sample scenario using my commands you can then grow the underlying raid1 halves and verify directly that the "obvious" process works (`mdadm -grow`, etc.). Alternatively I can extend my answer with a tested scenario in about a week

Comment: Would happily wait for you to complete this answer as I'm also on holiday. Enjoy it! :) Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel there you go